# ERROR: Volume "...telegraf.conf:ro has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]" when running the "docker-compose up" command

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, telegraf

Good day!
I get error, when running the "docker-compose up" command

Full error:
`ERROR: Volume /home/<...>/docker/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]`

I tried it:

- Change the value of the docker version in Docker-compose.yml on 20.10.8 and 20. I get a version error
- Put ./telegraf. conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf. conf:ro in quotation marks ("/telegraf. conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf. conf:ro in quotation marks"). I get the same error
- Delete ":ro" from /telegraf. conf: / etc/telegraf/telegraf. conf:ro. Starts loading containers, but returns an error in the "telegraf" block

My OS: Ubuntu Mate (distro Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
Docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Please tell me how to fix/bypass the error so that all the components are loaded

Docker-compose.yml:

```
# docker-compose up

version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=goby_test
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - PGDATA=/data/postgres
    image: "postgres:9.6.23-alpine"
    mem_limit: 128M
    cpus: 0.1
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready --username=postgres && psql --username=postgres --list"
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.8-alpine
    platform: linux/x86_64
    mem_limit: 1024M
    cpus: 0.5
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=influx
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./influxdb/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    # - influxdb_data:/var/lib/influxdb
  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:1.19.2-alpine
    container_name: telegraf
    platform: linux/x86_64
    mem_limit: 128M
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    links:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - "8125:8125/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:8.1.1
    platform: linux/x86_64
    mem_limit: 128M
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    links:
      - influxdb
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED=false
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      # - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
      - ./grafana/dashboards/:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/
  web:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
    image: gobylang/todo-sample:latest
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - "52022:22"
    mem_limit: 64M
    cpus: 0.1
    entrypoint: goby server.gb --bind 0.0.0.0:3000 wsgi
  tank:
    image: direvius/yandex-tank
    #    image: ovil/ltws-tank
    #    environment:
    #      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    volumes:
      - ../:/data
    cap_add: [NET_ADMIN]
    depends_on:
      - web
      - grafana
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
  k6:
    image: loadimpact/k6:0.33.0
    ports:
      - 6565:6565
    environment:
      - K6_OUT=influxdb=http://influxdb:8086/k6
    #      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    volumes:
      - ../:/data
    cap_add: [NET_ADMIN]
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - web
      - influxdb
      - grafana
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null

volumes:
  grafana_data: {}
  influxdb_data: {}
```

Comment: Do you have a colon in the path to your external file?

Comment: @BertC, yes, there is a colon in the line "- ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro"

Comment: I mean that the "./" in the path is translated to the full path. If there is a colon in that full path which you don't see because the relative path is used, then it would result in 3 colons instead of 2.